# How to replace an instance in __init__() with a different object?

Tags: python, oop

I am calling a constructor in ClassA and want to have the resulting object be of a different class (ClassB) if a certain condition is met.  I've tried replacing the first argument to __init__() ('self' in the example below) *within* __init__() but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

in main:

```
import ClassA

my_obj = ClassA.ClassA(500)
# unfortunately, my_obj is a ClassA, but I want a ClassB!
```

in ClassA/__init__.py:

```
import ClassB

class ClassA:
    def __init__(self,theirnumber):
        if(theirnumber > 10):
            # all big numbers should be ClassB objects:
            self = ClassB.ClassB(theirnumber)
            return
        else:
            # numbers under 10 are ok in ClassA.
            return
```

in ClassB/__init__.py:

```
class ClassB:
    pass
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You need `__new__()` for that. (And you also need to make it a new-style class, assuming you're using Python 2, by subclassing `object`.)

```
class ClassA(object):
    def __new__(cls,theirnumber):
        if theirnumber > 10:
            # all big numbers should be ClassB objects:
            return ClassB.ClassB(theirnumber)
        else:
            # numbers under 10 are ok in ClassA.
            return super(ClassA, cls).__new__(cls, theirnumber)
```

`__new__()` runs as part of the class instantiation process before `__init__()`. Basically `__new__()` is what actually creates the new instance, and `__init__()` is then called to initialize its properties. That's why you can use `__new__()` but not `__init__()` to alter the type of object created: once `__init__()` starts, the object has already been created and it's too late to change its type. (Well... not really, but that gets into very arcane Python black magic.) See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization).

In this case, though, I'd say a factory function is more appropriate, something like

```
def thingy(theirnumber):
    if theirnumber > 10:
        return ClassB.ClassB(theirnumber)
    else:
        return ClassA.ClassA(theirnumber)
```

By the way, note that if you do what I did with `__new__()` above, if a `ClassB` is returned, the `__init__()` method you wrote in `ClassA` will *not* be called on the `ClassB` instance! When you construct the `ClassB` instance *inside* `ClassA.__new__()`, its own `__init__()` method (`ClassB.__init__()`) will be run at that point, so hopefully it makes sense that Python shouldn't run another unrelated `__init__()` method on the same object. But this can get kind of confusing, which is probably another argument in favor of the factory function approach.

Comment: Ok, now what if I want to swap out the object with a new one inside of an object method, instead of in the constructor?  I want an object that turns into other objects during its lifecycle.

Comment: @sneak, you can't: method gets `self` as an argument and so whatever they may rebind to said barename it won't have any effect outside the method.  (You can of course rebind **qualified** names such as `self.__class__` -- qualified names and barenames are totally different in just about every respect you can think of).

Comment: @Alex, the fact that you can assign to `self.__class__` is an accident of implementation in CPython; the official python spec says that this *should not* work. Even if it wasn't an accident, it's a pretty horrible thing to do. In short: please don't, and especially please don't suggest it to other people.

Comment: @Aaron, please point me to the "official python spec" that says this should not work -- I think you're wrong, as the only mention I see in the language specs, at http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots , says `__class__ assignment works only if both classes have the same __slots__` (and so in particular is guaranteed to work if neither class has any `__slots__`).  Much as I think you're provably wrong in what you state as a fact about "this should not work", I think you're off your rocker in saying "it's a pretty horrible thing": it's a fine technique when needed (not often).

Comment: @Alex, http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#id1
I remembered that sentence, though not the footnote. Either way, the footnote seems to agree with me in the horrability of this.

Comment: @Aaron, "it _generally_ is not a good idea" means it **is** a good idea in the rare cases when it's needed (not often, as I said).  And of course it's wrong to "handle it incorrectly" (d'uh).  That's a **far** cry from "pretty horrible thing", no matter how you twist it.

Comment: I have to agree with Alex that it could be appropriate under certain very specific circumstances, and I've never heard that this behavior is an implementation accident. But I didn't want to complicate my answer by explaining that behavior - that's why I referred to it as "arcane Python black magic." I personally have never had an appropriate situation to use that feature (and I've done some weird stuff in Python).

Answer (score 21):

I would suggest using a **factory pattern** for this. For example:

```
def get_my_inst(the_number):
   if the_number > 10:
       return ClassB(the_number)
   else:
       return ClassA(the_number)

class_b_inst = get_my_inst(500)
class_a_inst = get_my_inst(5)
```

Answer (score 17):

Don't try to pervert the purpose of constructors: use a factory function.  Calling a constructor for one class and being returned an instance of a different class is a sure way to cause confusion.