# Equivalent of perl bless in python

Tags: python, perl

```
A.pm
new {
   my $_this = bless(+{}, __PACKAGE__);
   $_this->{_native} = 1;
   $_this->{_type} = 'cmd';
   if ($this->{_type}) {
    $class = 'A::B';
   } else {
     $class = 'A::C';
   }
    Class::Autouse->load($class);
    $this = bless($_this, $class);
    $this->new();
}

In side A/B.pm

use parent qw(A);
```

So here B is derived from A, but when  I call A->new(type = ''), and object of B/C is created  based on the type passed.
Can anyone please suggest how this can be achieved in python?

Comment: What is the difference between `$_this` and `$this` ? Shouldn't you declare `$this` with `my $this` somewhere ?

Comment: See also [How to replace an instance in __init__() with a different object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3209233/2173773)

Comment: What you're looking for is the Factory pattern. Google "python factory pattern" and you should find various implementations.

Answer (score 1):

> object of B/C is created based on the type passed

There's nothing special about `new` in Perl; it's just an ordinary sub. Nothing stops you from doing the same in Python.

```py
def new(cmd):
   if type == 'cmd':
      return A()
   else:
      return B()
```

---

As for the title,

```perl
package MyClass {
   sub new {
      my ($class, $foo, $bar) = @_;
      my $self = bless({}, $class);
      $self->{foo} = $foo;
      $self->{bar} = $bar;
      return $self;
   }
}

my $o = Class->new($foo, $bar);
```

is equivalent to

```py
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, foo, bar):
      self.foo = foo
      self.bar = bar

   def new(a_class, foo, bar):
      return a_class(foo, bar)

o = MyClass.new(MyClass, foo, bar)
print(o.foo)
```

But you'd normally write

```py
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, foo, bar):
      self.foo = foo
      self.bar = bar

o = MyClass(foo, bar)
```